# How to get the icon for a file type on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, icons

On Linux I can use this pipeline [`QMimeDatabase::mimeTypeForFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html#mimeTypeForFile) > [`QMimeType::iconName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimetype.html#iconName-prop) > [`QIcon::fromTheme`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme) to get icons for files. Afaik the latter works on Linux only.

How can I get icons for mimetype on macOS? Do I have to use [`icon(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3553230-icon) and create the pixmap on my own, or are there better ways?

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

To get the icon for a file use [`QFileIconProvider::icon`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html#icon-2) with [`QFileInfo`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#QFileInfo-3) like that:

```
QIcon fileIcon = QFileIconProvider().icon(QFileInfo(fileName));
```

### Example

Here is a simple example I wrote for you to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileIconProvider>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *btnOpen = new QPushButton(tr("Open File"), this);

        btnOpen->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        l->addWidget(btnOpen);

        connect(btnOpen, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::onFileOpen);

        resize(300, 300);
    }

private slots:
    void onFileOpen() {
        const QString &fileName(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File")));

        if (fileName.isEmpty())
            return;

        auto *btnOpen = static_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());

        btnOpen->setIcon(QFileIconProvider().icon(QFileInfo(fileName)));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```